# How to apply officer::read_docx to whole folder

Tags: r, loops, lapply, docx, officer

I am attempting to scan many documents, with the purpose of reorganizing the text into a standard format. This involves either extracting the table using `docxtractr`, and extracting the body text separately using `textreadr`, or using `officer::docx_summary` to label the body and table text for easier manipulation. For this problem, I'm using `officer::read_docx` and `officer::docx_summary`. The test documents I'm using are `.docx`, and contain nonsense text before and after a table that includes text and numbers.

My code is:

```
dir <- "C:/path/to/documents"
filenames <- list.files(path = dir, pattern = "*.docx", full.names = TRUE)
docxtest <- officer::docx_summary(lapply(filenames, officer::read_docx))
```

Ideally it would produce a list of dataframes that contain the `docx_summary` information. I tried to use `lapply` on a list of filenames, but the output list gives an error when trying to view:

```
Error in names[[i]]: subscript out of bounds.
```

Comment: Have you tried the function on a single filename path first? Please provide some example input data, if you'd like someone to attempt to reproduce and fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`officer::docx_summary` is for an object returned by `officer::read_docx`, it does not support list...

```
filenames <- list.files(path = dir, pattern = "*.docx", full.names = TRUE)
docxtest <- lapply(filenames, function(x) officer::docx_summary(officer::read_docx(x)) )
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you so much for correcting my syntax. This works.